# Tool for Designing Polygons

Tags: javafx-2, polygon

I am looking to design a large number of polygon (geometric not 3D) shapes for use in a JavaFX 2 application.
At the moment the only way I find to do that is manually enter every point for the polygons into and fxml file. Although this is a very slow process. I can not find a way to use Scene builder for this. When you create a polygon, its initially a triangle, and there is no apparent way of how to add more points.

Is there any free(or cheap) application that allows you to design shapes, and then give you all coordinates for the points ?

Im using OSX but also got win7.

p.s: If this is not the right place for this question please let me know.

Comment: If you will not find a good answer - you can create this tool by yourself. =) just add a canvas on the scene, and track coordinates of mouse click.

Comment: Yes that would be the last hope although I really dislike working with graphics and interfaces therefore I want to avoid it if possible. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Current version of Scene Builder has poor support for shape manipulation.
For polygons you can find a lot of editors by google "free vector editor". You can use Inkscape for example. It supports SVG format which simple to emmbed to JavaFX by java code, fxml or css.